# How do i open a PDF file in Netbeans?

Tags: java, pdf, netbeans

I want my application to open a pdf file when I click a dedicated button. How would i approach this? Also if I run the application from netbeans it shows the pdf but when compiled nothing comes up?

My code

```
    private void showHelpMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        File f = new File("ana.pdf");
    try {
      Desktop.getDesktop().open(f);
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);}
```

Comment: fyi: those error messages are not relevant (plus they aren't errors, they are warnings)

Comment: First of all, it's warning from th compiler stating that the flag "-source 1.5" will be removed in the future. Second, if it failed to open the PDF didn't open, it should have shown an error message

Comment: I deduce it's a file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly give the entire file path, which might solve your problem.  Also the OS you are using must support the operation.  This might help:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                    try {
                        File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\klinks\\Documents\\pdf.pdf");
                        Desktop.getDesktop().open(myFile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // System probably doesn't have a default PDF program
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets the file from the current directory. The file is there when you run it from netbeans, but the file is not there when you run it.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this. I think the best idea would be write the documentation as HTML, put it on a server, and open the web browser (using `Desktop.browse`). If someone else has a better idea, please comment.